# Effectiveness of PointerMoved event in Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, events, canvas, windows-store-apps

I am writting a Windows Store App where you can draw lines on the screen and need to avoid the obstacles. To detect where exactly is user touching at the moment I use `Canvas` from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls`, because it contains events that are helpful here. But the problem is that `PointerMoved` event is very slow, and it's easy for user to draw on the obstacle and app does not detect it (if user draws over the obstacle fast enough)

Is there any way to speed it up, for example try to force this event to be raised after every (even small) pointer position change?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may want to try looking into a custom GestureRecognizer, or possibly using a `SwapChainPanel`. The latter connects to the `DirectX` runtime and has a lot of useful functionality, such as [`CreateCoreIndependentInputSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel.createcoreindependentinputsource.aspx) which allows you to handle input processing on a background thread. [This sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SwapChainPanel-00cb688b) has an example of rendering ink strokes, which sounds like what you want to do.